# DATEDIFF in MySQL with ranges extending new year

Tags: mysql

I have a database table with holiday requests in it. I now want to calculate, how many days the user has requested for a certain year. So far I did this:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `holidays` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `begin` date NOT NULL,
  `end` date NOT NULL,
  `comment_user` text NOT NULL,
  `entered_at` int(11) NOT NULL  
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Get all holidays in a year:

```
SELECT SUM((DATEDIFF(end, begin) + 1)) AS days 
FROM holidays 
WHERE user = :user AND begin LIKE '2021%'
```

But what can I do, if **begin date** is in the year before (e.g. 12/30/2020) or **end date** is in the next year (e.g. 01/05/2022), so the request extends over new year's eve.

> **EXAMPLE**:
>
> If I have a holiday request from **12/30/2020 to 01/02/2021**, I wanna count just two days of that, not all four days.
> Only the days in 2021

Is there any possibilty to limit the **DATEDIFF** calculation to 01/01/2021 AND 12/31/2021, but getting all requests affected in that year?
And how can I put that in one mysql-query? I can't find any solution on google for that.

Would be great, if someone had a similar problem and solved that.

Thank's in advance,
Tobias

Comment: Show table structure as its CREATE TABLE, and some data example.

Comment: Hey @Akina, is that better to understand now?

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample database like this ([FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8adf1a817bf0e59937ac24238480535b)):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `holidays` (
  `begin` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end` date DEFAULT NULL
)
INSERT INTO `holidays` VALUES 
    ('2020-12-28','2021-01-05'),
    ('2020-12-05','2020-12-06'),
    ('2021-01-06','2021-01-06');
```

This SQL-statement:

```sql
select 
   begin, 
   CASE WHEN year(end)>year(begin) then ADDDATE(makedate(year(`end`),1),INTERVAL -1 DAY) else `end` end as END , 
   year(begin) as year
from holidays
union all
select
   makedate(year(`end`),1),
   `end`,
   year(`end`)
from holidays
where year(`begin`)<>year(`end`);
```

will have as output:

```
+------------+------------+------+
| begin      | END        | year |
+------------+------------+------+
| 2020-12-28 | 2020-12-31 | 2020 |
| 2020-12-05 | 2020-12-06 | 2020 |
| 2021-01-06 | 2021-01-06 | 2021 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 |
+------------+------------+------+
```

BTW: One should never use, or at least try to avoid, [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) in a table definition (like 'begin', 'end')

Comment: Wow, awesome @Luuk! Thank you very much for your response!!! I will try that query! And thanks for the advise with the reserved words. I will change that as well.